# Create auto alias of every folder in a specific folder in bash_profile or bash_alias

Tags: bash, alias

Using *macOS Sonoma 14.2.1*

We created an alias in `.bash_profile` or `.zsh_profile` and added the alias like this:

```sh
alias dev='cd ~/Developer'
```

Now there are many folders inside this and for each project I have to create alias for that to access early.

Now in *Developer* folder there are 3 project folders:

```
.Developer
├── apple
├── canvas
└── demo
```

Currently, I created separate alias for each folder to access them as below:

```sh
alias apple='cd ~/Developer/apple'
alias canvas='cd ~/Developer/canvas'
alias demo='cd ~/Developer/demo'
```

This works fine but I am looking for any optimal solution or bash script which automatically generate an alias for each folder of a specific folder and add into `.bash_profile`.

Or when creating new folder in this directory, it automatically adds new alias for the new folder.

Comment: Say you have a directory ~/foo/tmp  and an otherone ~/bar/tmp : Into which of those should the alias `tmp` then change?

Comment: Perhaps not **exactly** what you want, but have a look at the bash option `autocd` and the environment variable `CDPATH`. Maybe a clever use of those two would do what you want, without the need of using a script for generating those aliases.

Comment: @user1934428 The OP wants to `cd` to directories in `~/Developer`. The main risk is that one of their projects will be named the same as an existing command/binary.

Comment: Also, didn't know about `autocd`. Combined with CDPATH it will do exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @nohillside : He can simply set `CDPATH` to ~/Developer, and turn on _autocd_.  Of course there is a possibility of a name clash with a binary of the same name, but this problem exists as well, if he generates the aliases by a script. For interactive use, I expect the OP to be aware of these possibilities, and they can always be disambiguated if necessary. A similar problem exists, if you have a binary in your PATH shadowed by another one earlier in the PATH, or shadowed by an alias or function.

Comment: what means by CDPATH ? is it using cd command everytime?

Comment: Check the description in the man page. Basically, CDPATH is a list of directories. Each time you type `cd foo`, every directory in CDPATH will be checked whether it has a subdirectory named `foo`. If one does, current directory changes to it.

Comment: that everyone knows. its very common and basic thing and this is how we always do but issue is sometime we have to navigate far deeper folder.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you give an example in relation to the question you asked above?

Answer (score 6):

It might be easier to add `~/Developer` to `CDPATH` (works in both `bash` and `zsh`) and then use `cd fancyproject` to change to `~/Developer/fancyproject`.

But if you want to go with aliases, and assuming you are using your shell to create new development directories, you can include a shell function in `~/.bash_profile` to create the directory, an alias in the current shell and an entry in `~/.bash_profile` in one go by running `mkdevdir fancyproduct`.

```bash
function mkdevdir() {
    [[ "$1" ]] || return 1

    local _dev=~/Developer
    [[ -e "${_dev}/$1" ]] && return 2

    mkdir "${_dev}/$1"
    alias $1="cd ${_dev}/$1"
    echo "alias $1=\"cd ${_dev}/$1\"" >> ~/.bash_profile
}
```

**CAVEAT:** If your new project has the same name as an existing command, the newly created alias will take precedence. Use `\name` to suppress alias expansion.

Comment: will give it a try

Comment: @xkeshav Please have a look at the comments beneath the question. Setting the `autocd` option and adding `~/Developer` to `CDPATH` will give you the same functionality, without the shell function (and the need to fix things each time you just use `mkdir`).